# Strange behavior of Height constraint of UITableView cell in IOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

After upgrade on IOS 15 my previous code start works strange.

I have UITableView with cells with embedded views. When it loads in viewDidLoad cell's height constrain that I setup in storyboard become active and cell become close. Tap on cell makes height constraint become not active and cell open.
Height constraint for foldView

But in IOS 15 cell always open when loading. Even if height constraint is active.

here my code that makes it open or close:

```
var expanded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            let duration = CATransaction.animationDuration()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                self.arrow.transform = self.expanded ? CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2) :  .identity
               
                self.height.priority = .defaultHigh
                self.height.isActive = !self.expanded
                self.foldView.alpha = self.expanded ? 1 : 0
                self.container.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
            
        }
    }
```

and this is how I add embedded view:

```
func addEmbeddedView(_ view: UIView) {
        self.foldView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        self.foldView.addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let constraints = [
            view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.foldView.leadingAnchor),
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.foldView.trailingAnchor),
            view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.foldView.topAnchor),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.foldView.bottomAnchor, constant: -9)
        ]
        constraints[3].priority = .defaultHigh
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
```

BUT! if I tap on cell from

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else { return }
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        cell.expanded.toggle()
        tableView.fixCellBounds()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

all works as expected and cell open and close in IOS 15 too.

Any suggestions what it could be?
As I assume in IOS 15 was some changes in AutoLayout that may affect my code..

Here my full custom cell class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var arrowImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var foldView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var arrow: UIImageView!

    let layer1 = CALayer(), layer2 = CALayer(), layer3 = CALayer()

    var expanded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            let duration = CATransaction.animationDuration()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                self.arrow.transform = self.expanded ? CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2) :  .identity
               
                self.height.priority = .defaultHigh
                self.height.isActive = !self.expanded
         
                self.foldView.alpha = self.expanded ? 1 : 0
                self.container.layoutIfNeeded()
               
            }
            
        }
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var height: NSLayoutConstraint!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.expanded = false
        
        
        container.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        container.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
        container.backgroundColor = Colors_8_5.offWhite.color
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear

        self.container.clipsToBounds = true
        self.contentView.clipsToBounds = false
        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.selectionStyle = .none
        self.backgroundColor = .clear

        [layer1, layer2, layer3].forEach {
            $0.masksToBounds = false
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer($0, at: 0)
        }

        
    }

    func configure(with model: CustomCellModel) {
        self.headerLabel.attributedText = model.header
        self.descriptionLabel.attributedText = model.text
        self.descriptionLabel.isHidden = model.text == nil
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    }

    func addEmbeddedView(_ view: UIView) {
        self.foldView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        self.foldView.addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let constraints = [
            view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.foldView.leadingAnchor),
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.foldView.trailingAnchor),
            view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.foldView.topAnchor),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.foldView.bottomAnchor, constant: -9)
        ]
        constraints[3].priority = .defaultHigh
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        [layer1, layer2, layer3].forEach {
            $0.frame = container.frame
        }

        layer1.CustomapplySketchShadow(color: .black, alpha: 0.04, x: 0, y: 4, blur: 8, spread: 0)
        layer2.CustomapplySketchShadow(color: .black, alpha: 0.04, x: 0, y: 16, blur: 24, spread: 0)
        layer3.CustomapplySketchShadow(color: .black, alpha: 0.04, x: 0, y: 24, blur: 32, spread: 0)

    }

}


extension CALayer {
    func CustomapplySketchShadow(
        color: UIColor = .black,
        alpha: Float = 0.2,
        x: CGFloat = 0,
        y: CGFloat = 2,
        blur: CGFloat = 4,
        spread: CGFloat = 0)
    {
        shadowColor = color.cgColor
        shadowOpacity = alpha
        shadowOffset = CGSize(width: x, height: y)
        shadowRadius = blur / 2
        if spread == 0 {
            shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        } else {
            let dx = -spread
            let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dx, dy: dx)
            shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a custom cell.  Expanded I declare in my custom cell class. I add code above. addEmbeddedView - my func in my custom cell class. I also add code above.

Comment: I add full class!)